# `read()` system call in C does not read bytes

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm trying to read characters from a file and count the frequency of a particular word in a file using system calls, but the behavior of one of my `read()` calls is confusing me. This is the code that I've written:

```
int counter, seekError,readVal;
counter = 0;

char c[1];
char *string = "word";

readVal = read(fd,c,1);
while (readVal != 0){ // While not the end of the file
    if(c[0] == string[0]) { // Match the first character
                seekError = lseek(fd,-1,SEEK_CUR); // After we find a matching character, rewind to capture the entire word
                char buffer[strlen(string)+1];
                buffer[strlen(string)] = '\0';
                readVal = read(fd,buffer,strlen(string)); // This read() does not put anything into the buffer

                if(strcmp(lowerCase(buffer),string) == 0)
                        counter++;

                lseek(fd,-(strlen(string)-1),SEEK_CUR); // go back to the next character
        }
        readVal = read(fd,c,1);
}
```

In all the read calls that I use, I am able to read characters with no problem from my file. However, the `readVal = read(fd,buffer,strlen9string));` line never puts anything into `buffer`, no matter how I try to read the characters. Is there anything going on behind the scenes that would explain this kind of behavior? I've tried running this code on different machines as well, but I still get nothing in `buffer` at that line.

Comment: What does the `read` function returns? If it's zero it means the "file" is closed, if negative it's an error and you need to check `errno` for whats wrong.

Comment: Also, *how* do you know that the `read` call doesn't work? It it's because the string comparison fails you might want to look at `lowerCase` instead? Either run in a debugger and step through the code line by line while watching the value and contents of all variables, or print the string (if `read` returns a positive number) directly after the `read`.

Comment: The call is returning 0, but this occurs after reading only three characters of 50 character file. As far as I know, the file isn't closed, nor is the file pointer at the end of the file. I also went through it in `gdb`, and all that was in the buffer was '\001'

Comment: Run  `strace` on your program. And study documentation of [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), notably failure cases. BTW your question is operating system (and perhaps file system) specific.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just checked out the output using `strace`, and it revealed the error instantly. I wasn't casting the `-1` correctly into the `off_t` type. Thanks for the heads up and for introducing me to `strace`!

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be necessary to cast `-1` into the `off_t` type. It looks like your real bug is that you didn't include `<unistd.h>` so `lseek` wasn't properly declared when you used it. Either that or there's a serious bug in your system's implementation of `lseek`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here was that the `-1` in the `seekError = lseek(fd,-1,SEEK_CUR);` line was being interpreted as `4294967295`. After casting it into the `off_t` type, the system interpreted the offset as `-1` instead of the large number.

So the corrected line is: `seekError = lseek(fd,(off_t)-1,SEEK_CUR);`